# Lambda function is (sometimes) timing out attempting to access s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, timeout, amazon-vpc

So i am attempting to create a lambda function inside of my vpc that requires s3 access. Most of the time it goes off without a hitch, however, sometimes it will just hang on s3.getObject until the function times out, there is no error when this happens. I have set up a VPC endpoint and the endpoint is in the route table for the (private) subnet, ensured that access to the endpoint is not being blocked by either the security group or NACL, and IAM permissions all seem to be in order (though if that was the issue one would expect an error message).

I've boiled my code down to a simple get/put for the purposes of debugging this issue, but here it is in case i am missing the incredibly obvious. I've spent hours googling this, tried everything suggested/i can think of... and am basically out of ideas at this point... so i cannot emphasize enough how much i appreciate any help that can be given

Update: i have run my code from an ec2 instance inside the same vpc/subnet/security group as the lambda... seems to not have the same problem, so the issue seems to be with the lambda configuration rather than any of the network configuration

````
    try {
        const getParams = {
            Bucket: 'MY_BUCKET',
            Key: '/path/to/file'
        };

        console.log('************** about to get', getParams);
        const getObject = await s3.getObject(getParams).promise();
        console.log('************** gotObject', getObject);
        const uploadParams = {
            Bucket: 'MY_BUCKET',
            Key: '/new/path/to/file',
            Body: getObject.Body
        };
        console.log('************** about to put', uploadParams);
        const putObject = await s3.putObject(uploadParams).promise();
        console.log('*************** object was put', putObject);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('***************** error', err);
    }
};```
````

Comment: This won't help but I can't really think of a good reason why this might happen. Certainly I've never experienced this behaviour, and we use a similar setup (vpc + s3 endpoint). Can you detect any sort of pattern about when it hangs? e.g. certain types of files, files that don't exist, file has just been deleted, certain times of day, lambda called in a certain way, etc... If you don't get anywhere with it, it might be worth raising a tech support ticket with aws, if you've got that stuff enabled on your account.

Comment: Yeah it makes absolutely no sense to me either ha. No pattern i can discern at the moment, if i set up a test that will have it pull the same file from the same bucket every time, and then click test 50 times in a row it will timeout ~5-10 times and succeed the rest, which makes it just appear random to me. adding further to the weirdness i've run my code from an instance inside the same vpc with the same security group and had no issues... so it seems to be something specific to lambda... i just have no idea what that could be

Comment: Are you able to repro this reasonably reliably, like 1 time in 50? Perhaps see what impact a larger RAM configuration has (which will give you correspondingly more CPU and network share).